# \tclap vs. \overset and \underset

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, mathtools, size, stackengine

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

a\kern0pt{\color{red}{\tclap[5pt]{$\overset{\text{2}}{\vee}$}}}\kern0pt{} %1

a{\color{red}{${\underset{\wedge}{{\text{2}}}}$}} %2

a\color{red}{$ {\overset{\vee}{{\text{2}}}}$} %3

\end{document}
```

I would like the dimensions of `\wedge` and `\vee` in the second and third expressions to match the dimension of `\vee` in the first expression.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `\wedge` and `\vee` with `\textstyle\wedge` and `\textstyle\vee`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

a{\color{red}\tclap[5pt]{$\overset{\text{2}}{\vee}$}} %1

a{\color{red}$\underset{\textstyle\wedge}{\text{2}}$} %2

a{\color{red}$\overset{\textstyle\vee}{\text{2}}$}    %3

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the exact opposite situation.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood your post. Edited the post to clarify meaning and edited my answer. Is this what you want now?

Comment: Yes, I what I want is.

Comment: I apologize. Because I can not write to you clearly.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of streamlining the code, e.g., by eliminating unneeded pairs of curly braces. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico I should have done that myself, but I left OP's code in place. Thanks for the cleanup.